# How does type conversion happens in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

```
(1) console.log(8*null)
```

// output to 0 ( null changes to 0)

```
(2) console.log("5"-1)
```

//output to 4 ("5" changes to 5)

```
(3) console.log("5"+1)
```

//output to "51" (1 changes to "1")

As if you see the above lines of code , some times type conversion happens on left hand side and some times it happens on right hand side of the binary operator.

So my question is how does JavaScript decides which operand type needs to be changed, does it happens internally (without in the knowledge of user) or is there any precedence of data type is there??

Comment: `'+'` will concatenate if any of the operand is of type `string`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Type_conversion

Comment: have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence to know whether left hand or right hand precedence takes places

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Because `*` is a [multiplicative operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-multiplicative-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation), it calls the specification's [`ToNumber`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tonumber) abstract operation on both of its operands (first the left one, then the right one). The result of `ToNumber(null)` is `0` (see the link for a table), so `8 * 0` is `0`.
2. Because `-` is a [subtraction operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-subtraction-operator-minus), it also calls `ToNumber` on its operands. So you get `5 - 1` which is `4`.
3. The [`+` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-addition-operator-plus) has two meanings: Mathematical addition, and string concatenation. If either operand is a string, you get concatenation, not addition. More formally: It first converts its operands to *primitives* via the spec's abstract [`ToPrimitive`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toprimitive) operation, and then determines whether either operand's primitive value is a string, and does concatenation if so. In the case of `+`, it doesn't matter which operand (the left or right) is a string, it can be either and that makes it concatenation rather than addition.

> So my question is how does JavaScript decides which operand type needs to be changed, does it happens internally (without in the knowledge of user) or is there any precedence of data type is there??

It's spelled out in very, very thorough detail in the specification, so if you have any doubts in a particular situation, that's where to look.